# JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I need to know if JasperReports Server 5.5.0 has support for Report Books?

I need to create a Report Book and we have the 5.5.0 version of JasperReports Server.

Comment: Report Books were added in version 6

Comment: Thanks for the info @jtsnr :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting @jtsnr comment to an answer   (community wiki)

[Report books](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/report-books) were added in jasper report **version 6**

However this does not mean you can't do similar in version 5, you just need to setup your own report structure.